# Changing options menu icon

Tags: android, onclick, android-optionsmenu

Lets say I have a options menu like below:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_page, menu);

    final MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Enter text to search(min. 3 chars)...");
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String searchQuery) {
            if (!mSearchView.isIconified()) {
                mSearchView.setIconified(true);
            }
            mSearchView.setQuery(searchQuery, false);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        saveState();
        finish();
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_bookmark) {
        FragmentAdapter adapter = (FragmentAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
        PageFragment fragment = (PageFragment)adapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager,mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        fragment.getContent();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bookmark Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Is there any way to check which icon set to options menu item also change it with another when clicked on it?

here is xml for options menu:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_bookmark"
    android:title="Bookmark"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_bookmark_empty" />
```

onclicking i want to check which icon bookmark has and change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code `menu.getItem(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_empty));`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check which drawable is currently set you can use this code

```
item.getIcon().getConstantState().equals
(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_empty).getConstantState())
```

and for setting new drawable you can use this code

```
item.setIcon(R.drawble.ic_bookmark_empty)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following condition in onOptionsItemSelected :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        saveState();
        finish();
    } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_bookmark) {

           if(item.getIcon() ==R.drawable.ic_bookmark_empty)
           {
               // call bookmark code
               item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_filled); // set your desired bookmark icon
           } else {
               // call remove bookmark code  
               item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_empty);  
           }

        FragmentAdapter adapter = (FragmentAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter();
        PageFragment fragment = (PageFragment)adapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager,mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
        fragment.getContent();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bookmark Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: can i change menu item icon in onCreate i.e, if I clicked on bookmark from list then it will display me data in webview with bookmark icon as filled